# Saturation Recovery - Why is $M_z = 0$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

[This article](http://www.umm.uni-heidelberg.de/inst/cbtm/ckm/lehre/techniquesofimagingsystems/10_medphys_mri_3_2sw.pdf), p. 13, describes the evolution of the longitudinal magnetisation in NMR, $M_z$, if a 90° pulse is shot. My question is:

1. why will $M_z$ become zero after every shot, since imediately before the 2nd pulse there might be transvers magnetization left (for example if $T_r \le T_1$) that should become $M_z \le 0$ after the pulse.
2. why does $M_z$ reach a constant maximum-value after every shot ($T_r$ = const)?

M_z is the longitudinal magnetization.

[image: Here the pic from p. 13 of the link]

Comment: What is M_Z? Please put vital information from the link in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

A very nice way to look at this problem is the [Bloch sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere). A $90^\circ$ pulse means that the bloch vector with components x:Mx y:My and z:Mz is rotated around the x axis. So if $M_z = 0,M_x=0,M_y=0$ really nothing happens.

If a $90^\circ$ pulse (with x or y polarization) is acting on a bloch vector with only nonvanishing z-component, the result will always be a pure $M_y$ (or $M_x$ for y-polarization of the microwave pulse) magnetization.

If $M_z$ is between $0$ and $M_0$ the vector that is rotated is just shorter than as for $M_z = M_0$ and the resulting $M_y$ components will be shorter.  This is clearly visible in the graph for $M_{xy}$. The second pulse and all consequent ones are smaller than the first one.